# terraform fmt -recursive -check エラーについて

Tags: github, aws-cloud9, terraform

## やりたいこと

---

terraform planを実行したい

## エラーコード

---

terraform planのterraform formatにて、

```
Run terraform fmt -recursive -check
#ここから追記しました
 terraform fmt -recursive -check
shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
env:
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-northeast-1
AWS_REGION: ap-northeast-1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
TERRAFORM_CLI_PATH: /home/runner/work/_temp/2d9e5f15-e175-4863-89e6-d79dbce8ee46
#ここまで追記しました

/home/runner/work/_temp/2d9e5f15-e175-4863-89e6-d79dbce8ee46/terraform-bin fmt -recursive -check
env/dev/main.tf
env/dev/terraform.tfvars
env/dev/variables.tf
env/prod/main.tf
env/prod/terraform.tfvars
env/prod/variables.tf
env/stg/main.tf
env/stg/terraform.tfvars
env/stg/variables.tf
module/aurora/main.tf
module/aurora/variables.tf
module/ec2/main.tf
module/ec2/variables.tf


Error: Terraform exited with code 3.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

## 使用している環境

---

cloud9で作業→githubにpushしてPRで反映
ブランチは
prod（default）
|＿stg
　　｜＿dev
　　　　|＿feature
となっていて、 featureで作業&pushしてリモート内で各リポジトリにPRしています

## 試したこと

---

`terraform fmt -recursive -check`とエラーに記載されているので
ローカルのfeatureブランチ上で`terraform fmt`を実行しました。
その際、特に変化がなかったため、別の作業が必要だと思い調べ中です。

このエラーについてご存知の方、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: terraformのバージョンはいくつですか？また、 `module/ec2/variables.tf` 単体に `terraform fmt` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`terraform fmt`をオプション付きで実行したログが出力されているだけで、エラーではないように見受けられます。

[Command: fmt | Terraform by HashiCorp](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/fmt#usage)

Comment: 回答とご丁寧にリンクをありがとうございます。
一部エラーコードに抜けがあったので追記しました。
また、エラー文を上記のエラーコードを追記したのですが、何行目で終了した、といった内容だけのため、どう対処したら良いのか…といった状態です

Comment: 私が回答したときは「Error: Terraform exited with code 3.Error: Process completed with exit code 1.」の情報がなかったので、エラーは発生していないと回答しましたが、誤っていたので取り消します。
terraform planを実行しても勝手にterraform fmtは実行されません。自動で実行する仕組みが入っているのでしょうか。例えば「GitHub Actionsでpush時にCIを回している」などが考えられますが、「自動で実行する仕組み」でエラーが発生しているとすると、こちらでは分かり兼ねますので、これ以上の回答は難しいです。